# Android toolbar back arrow does nothing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, toolbar, android-constraintlayout

I don't know why my back arrow on the toolbar does nothing, can anybody help me?

I leave here the onCreate of the activity, the adapter and the xml
Im using recyclerView with constraint layout

here is the code of the Activity "onCreate" class:

```
@Override
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(com.owncloud.android.R.layout.accounts_layout)
    tintedCheck = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, com.owncloud.android.R.drawable.ic_current_white)!!
    tintedCheck = DrawableCompat.wrap(tintedCheck)
    val tint = ContextCompat.getColor(this, com.owncloud.android.R.color.actionbar_start_color)
    DrawableCompat.setTint(tintedCheck, tint)

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(com.owncloud.android.R.id.account_list_recycler_view)
    recyclerView.run {
        filterTouchesWhenObscured = PreferenceUtils.shouldDisallowTouchesWithOtherVisibleWindows(applicationContext)
        adapter = accountListAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@AccountManagementActivity)
    }

    setupStandardToolbar(
        getString(com.owncloud.android.R.string.prefs_manage_accounts),
        displayHomeAsUpEnabled = true,
        homeButtonEnabled = true,
        displayShowTitleEnabled = true
    )

    val accountList = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(accountType)
    originalAccounts = toAccountNameSet(accountList)
    originalCurrentAccount = AccountUtils.getCurrentOwnCloudAccount(this).name

    accountListAdapter.submitAccountList(accountList = getAccountListItems())

    account = AccountUtils.getCurrentOwnCloudAccount(this)
    onAccountSet(false)

    /**
    // added click listener to switch account
    recyclerView.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
    switchAccount(
    position
    )
    }
     */
}
```

The code from the Adapter, implementing the recyclerView:

```
class AccountManagementAdapter(private val accountListener: AccountManagementActivity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var accountItemsList = listOf<AccountRecyclerItem>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        return if (viewType == AccountManagementRecyclerItemViewType.ITEM_VIEW_ACCOUNT.ordinal) {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_item, parent, false)
            view.filterTouchesWhenObscured = PreferenceUtils.shouldDisallowTouchesWithOtherVisibleWindows(parent.context)
            AccountManagementViewHolder(view)
        } else {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_action, parent, false)
            view.filterTouchesWhenObscured = PreferenceUtils.shouldDisallowTouchesWithOtherVisibleWindows(parent.context)
            NewAccountViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    fun submitAccountList(accountList: List<AccountRecyclerItem>) {
        accountItemsList = accountList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is AccountManagementViewHolder -> {
                val accountItem = getItem(position) as AccountRecyclerItem.AccountItem
                val account: Account = accountItem.account

                try {
                    val oca = OwnCloudAccount(account, holder.itemView.context)
                    holder.binding.name.text = oca.displayName
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.w(
                        "Account not found right after being read :\\ ; using account name instead of display " +
                                "name"
                    )
                    holder.binding.name.text = AccountUtils.getUsernameOfAccount(account.name)
                }
                holder.binding.name.tag = account.name

                holder.binding.account.text = DisplayUtils.convertIdn(account.name, false)

                try {
                    val avatarUtils = AvatarUtils()
                    avatarUtils.loadAvatarForAccount(
                        holder.binding.icon,
                        account,
                        true,
                        20f
                    )
                } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                    Timber.e(e, "Error calculating RGB value for account list item.")
                    // use user icon as a fallback
                    holder.binding.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user)
                }

                if (AccountUtils.getCurrentOwnCloudAccount(holder.itemView.context).name == account.name) {
                    holder.binding.ticker.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    holder.binding.ticker.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }

                /// bind listener to refresh account
                holder.binding.refreshAccountButton.apply {
                    setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh)
                    setOnClickListener { accountListener.refreshAccount(account) }
                }

                /// bind listener to change password
                holder.binding.passwordButton.apply {
                    setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_lock_reset_grey)
                    setOnClickListener { accountListener.changePasswordOfAccount(account) }
                }

                /// bind listener to remove account
                holder.binding.removeButton.apply {
                    setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_delete_grey)
                    setOnClickListener { accountListener.removeAccount(account) }
                }

                ///bind listener to switchAccount
                holder.binding.account.apply {
                    setOnClickListener { accountListener.switchAccount(position) }
                }
            }
            is NewAccountViewHolder -> {
                holder.binding.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_account_plus)
                holder.binding.name.setText(R.string.prefs_add_account)

                // bind action listener
                holder.binding.linearLayout.setOnClickListener {
                    accountListener.createAccount()
                }
            }
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = accountItemsList.size

    fun getItem(position: Int) = accountItemsList[position]

    sealed class AccountRecyclerItem {
        data class AccountItem(val account: Account) : AccountRecyclerItem()
        object NewAccount : AccountRecyclerItem()
    }

    class AccountManagementViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val binding = AccountItemBinding.bind(itemView)
    }

    class NewAccountViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val binding = AccountActionBinding.bind(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (getItem(position)) {
            is AccountRecyclerItem.AccountItem -> AccountManagementRecyclerItemViewType.ITEM_VIEW_ACCOUNT.ordinal
            is AccountRecyclerItem.NewAccount -> AccountManagementRecyclerItemViewType.ITEM_VIEW_ADD.ordinal
        }
    }

    enum class AccountManagementRecyclerItemViewType {
        ITEM_VIEW_ACCOUNT, ITEM_VIEW_ADD
    }

    /**
     * Listener interface for Activities using the [AccountListAdapter]
     */
    interface AccountAdapterListener {
        fun removeAccount(account: Account)
        fun changePasswordOfAccount(account: Account)
        fun refreshAccount(account: Account)
        fun createAccount()
        fun switchAccount(position: Int)
    }
}
```

and finally i leave you two xml files, which are the one where all the items are declared and the one where the recyclerView is implemented:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/accounts_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/owncloud_toolbar" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/account_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_plus"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ticker"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_current"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon" />
    <!-- drawable will be replaced by ic_current_white + tint in runtime;
    ic_current here as a placeholder -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_filename"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/refreshAccountButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ticker"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/standard_half_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_sentence"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/refreshAccountButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ticker"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refreshAccountButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@string/actionbar_sync"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/standard_half_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/standard_half_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/passwordButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/passwordButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/standard_half_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/standard_half_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_reset_grey"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/removeButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/standard_half_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/standard_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_delete_grey"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/black" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

if any more code is needed i can add it :)

i tried adding something like this:

```
if(item.getItemId() ==android.R.id.home){
  onBackPressed();
}
```

and something like this:

```
binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { navController.popBackStack() }
```

but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it adding this function at the activity class:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    var retval = true
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.home -> onBackPressed()
        else -> retval = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    return retval
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code where you define your `navController` :

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(yourNavController, null) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```

Comment: I don't have navigation component here :(

Comment: In order to control navigations or back buttons, you need to have navigation component or manually defined fragment transactions. If you do not have these the back button does not know where to go and not work. This document will help you [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)